# Custom control Lib with multiple controls and generic.xaml

Tags: wpf, controls

if i define two default styles for two different controls in one custom control lib i get errors...

is it possible to have two or more controls with a default generic.xaml in one lib?

Thanks

Comment: Please post (a lot) more information.  Also, you are more likely to get answers if you vote and select appropriate answers for other questions you've asked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The recommended approach is to place styles for each control in its own resource dictionary and have one Generic.xaml file that will reference others.

So, for example, if you have two controls in your library: MyControl1 and MyControl2. Then you will have the following files in the `Themes` folder of your project:

- generic.xaml
- MyControl1.generic.xaml
- MyControl2.generic.xaml

And your generic.xaml will look like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyControlLib;component/Themes/MyControl1.generic.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyControlLib;component/Themes/MyControl2.generic.xaml" />        
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>       


</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Yes - I personally think this is much better style.  I wish the default behavior in the IDE did this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Not only is it possible, it is the default behavior.

This is, of course, assuming that the two controls are in the same namespace.

You don't specify the error(s) that you are getting, so I can't offer much more detail.

Comment: I retry it and let you know my result! Thank you.

Comment: Ok it worked. I'm sorry i can't reproduce my error. I remember that i created a custom control lib with 2 classes and one generic.xaml... Very strange... Anyway thanks for that great concept => for each control a own rd :)