# Why can't I see the control of my WPF custom control?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have followed the solution of this question: [how to have many wpf custom controls in the same library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643839/how-to-have-many-wpf-custom-controls-in-the-same-library#39644094)

The problem now is that I can see the controls of my custom control when I add the custom control in my main view.

However, if I have the style in the generic.xaml file instead of the MyControl.xaml file, and only I have ona user control, it works.

The code of my MyControl.xaml is this:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomControls.Calendario2">


    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CalendarioMes2}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CalendarioMes2}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

                        <Grid>
                            <TextBox Text="Prueba" BorderBrush="Black"/>
                            <Label Content="Prueba" BorderBrush="black"/>
                        </Grid>

                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And the generic.xaml has this code:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomControls.Calendario2">


        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/CustomControls.Calendario2;component/ResourceDictionaries/CalendarioMes2.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Why can't I see the textBox and the label?

Thanks.

EDIT: I have use the absolute path to the file:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="F:\Alvaro\ejemplos\Calendario\CustomControls\Themes\CalendarioMes2.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

But know I have an error in the main window that say that I can create a type from the text. The error is in the CalendarioMes2.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomControls.Calendario2">


    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CalendarioMes2}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CalendarioMes2}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

                        <Grid>
                            <TextBox Text="Prueba" BorderBrush="Black"/>
                            <Label Content="Prueba" BorderBrush="black"/>
                        </Grid>

                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In the line 7:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CalendarioMes2}">
```

But compare my code with the code of the solution in the other thread, I see that I have the same line.

This is CalendarioMes2.cs

```
namespace CustomControls.Calendario2
{
    public class CalendarioMes2 : Control
    {
        static CalendarioMes2()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CalendarioMes2), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CalendarioMes2)));
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: the source code is here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiTepLSbavZ0gRDvBPJgrxEIWS1U

Comment: Your merged dictionary is looking for a file called CalendarioMes2.xaml, is that correct? Your question suggests it's called MyControl.xaml? Can you also share with us CalendarioMes2.cs?

Comment: Yes. my xaml is called CalendarioMes2.xaml.

Comment: Can you share your control with us? Likely named CalendarioMes2.cs?

Comment: I have added the CAlendarioMes2.cs code.

Comment: You're not showing us something, I created a brand new project. Only contains three files CalendarioMes2.cs, Generic.xaml, CalendarioMes2.xaml, I've named the assembly CustomControls.Calendario2, same with namespace. The first two code snippets along with your CalendarioMes2.cs build fine?

Comment: Yes, it builds good, the error is in runtime.

Comment: I'm assuming you are creating a library with what you have shown so far? This library is being used by another project, that project is throwing an error when trying to create a CalendarioMes2 object? I'm guessing CustomControls.Calendario2 has different dependencies, does it target a different framework?

Comment: The solution has two projects. A WPF application that use this custom control and a WPF custom control library project that has this code. Both target to .NET 4.6.1 version.

Comment: I have add the source code, perhaps it can be more clear.

Comment: I took a look, your project is working on my machine. I did make a few changes. I don't have .NET 4.6.1 so I targeted 4.5 I also changed Generic.xaml slightly. <ResourceDictionary Source="/CustomControls;component/Themes/CalendarioMes2.xaml"/> Otherwise it ran for me as-is.